# Configure a WCF service to authenticate the client by using X509 certificates but without server credentials

Tags: wcf, security, x509certificate

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC website that also hosts a WCF 4 service; and I have created a .NET Windows application that complements the website and interacts with it by consuming that web service via the internet. Both programs were created using .NET 4 in Visual Studio 2010. The binding used with the WCF service is a WsHttpBinding.

My *only* security requirement is that the WCF service is not consumed by some unknown party, as that would contaminate the information in my website's database. I have no need for any privacy: I don't care if some third party gets to see the messages I am sending to the web service (i.e., no need for encryption)

Considering that single requirement, and as far as my knowledge about security in web services goes, the best way to implement that security scenario would be for the client to sign each SOAP message with a X509 Certificate, and have the web service trust any message signed with a certificate present in its "trusted people" store. Since certificates use Public/Private key pairs, even if the message is not encrypted it cannot be reproduced by an unauthorized third party without the private key used to sign the message. This would also assure me message integrity.

Considering that decision, I have created a test certificate using makecert.exe. I installed the version with *both* the private and public key in the client machine (the one with the windows application), in the "Current User" "My" certificate store. Then, I exported the certificate (without the private key), and installed it in "Trusted People" of "Local Machine" certificate store of the web server.

My (unsuccessful) attempt to configure that scenario so far goes like this:

Binding is configured to use Message security, where the Message expects client credentials of the certificate type. Also, the server is configured to use PeerTrust instead of ChainTrust, since the test certificate is not emitted by a trusted CA:

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Standard">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode = "PeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
        </clientCertificate>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The configuration on the client windows application sets the certificate as its credential. The binding configuration is identical to the one in the server.

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="CertificateCredential">
      <clientCredentials>
        <clientCertificate findValue="ErrEye"
                           storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                           storeName="My"
                           x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The problem is that with this configuration, when I try to check if the Web Service host was started successfully, I get the following error:

```
The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials.
```

My problem is, I don't WANT to specify a "service certificate". As far as I understand, the service certificate would allow the client to authenticate the service, but I don't need that; I just want the service to authenticate the client and that's it. I **do** understand this means that if someone impersonates the web server (by tampering the DNS settings of my client computer, for example) it would receive the messages from my client and the client would not know it is not communicating with its intended recipient: I don't mind if that happens.

In summary, my question is: How do I configure in WCF the security scenario I've described?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As long as its .net to .net (and remains so) - add this

```
negotiateServiceCredential=true
```

to:

```
<message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
```

But beware, you will lose interoperability with non .net clients.

Comment: Unfortunately, the service host still won't start and displays the same error about specifying a service credential. Tried with negotiateServiceCredential in both "true" and "false".